# How to assess even and odd numbers using the bitwise operator &

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, binary

I am trying to assess if the numbers inside an array are even or odd using the bitwise operator &.

This is my code:

```
    arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 18, 361, 5622, 5623]
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        if (parseInt(el.toString(2)) & 1 === 0) {
            console.log(`${el} in binary is ${el.toString(2)} and it is an EVEN number`);
        } else {
            console.log(`${el} in binary is ${el.toString(2)} and it is an ODD number`);
        }
    });
```

Taking each element individually each one returns 0 or 1 which would assess if a number is even or odd, but in this case they all return ODD numbers.
This is what I get as result:

1 in binary is 1 and it is an ODD number

2 in binary is 10 and it is an ODD number

4 in binary is 100 and it is an ODD number

and so on...

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of operations matters here (and is defined by [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)). The `&` occurs after the `===` comparison, so your if-statement actually evaluates like:

```
if (parseInt(el.toString(2)) & (1 === 0)) {
```

where `1===0` is performed first. This will result in `if(<num> & false)`, where `false` is converted to the numeric value `0` as it is being used in the context of the bitwise `&` operator. So, `<num> & 0` will always evaluate to `0`, which is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (thus always causing the `else`-block to trigger).

Instead, you can use parenthesis to enforce the order:

```js
arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 18, 361, 5622, 5623]
arr.forEach(function(el) {
  if ((el & 1) === 0) {
    console.log(`${el} in binary is ${el.toString(2)} and it is an EVEN number`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${el} in binary is ${el.toString(2)} and it is an ODD number`);
  }
});
```

You can also use the `&` operator on your number directly (so no need to use toString on it)

Comment: 'el & 1' is already a comparison so you should be able to ommit '=== 0' but you would have to adapt the message.

Comment: I wouldn't call `el & 1` a comparison, but you're right, the `=== 0` can be omitted as when `el & 1` evaluates to `0` it would be considered falsy. I think checking if it equals `0` in the condition with `===` is more direct and clear that's it's checking that the bitwise `&` evaluates to `0` though.